# How to redirect https to https with www using AWS application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, http-redirect

Can anyone please help me to figure out redirection issue with AWS application load balancer?

I have -

- Deployed React JS app on EC2 - Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx
- Obtained SSL from AWS ACM
- Attached ALB to EC2 instance, added 2 listeners - PORT 80, PORT 443 (Forwarding request to target group on PORT 80)
- added CNAME record www pointing to ALB

Also, I have added redirect rule in listener 443 as -

[image]

But when I am visiting my site like - https://exampledomain.ai
it throws **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**

**Update:**  When I visit -

```
mydomain.ai //redirected to https://www.mydomain.ai
http://mydomain.ai //redirected to https://www.mydomain.ai
http://www.mydomain.ai //redirected to https://www.mydomain.ai
```

Is there anything else I am missing? Please help

Comment: "nxdomain" means that the hostname couldn't be resolved through DNS. Check if it's a local problem by entering the domain name here: https://dns-lookup.jvns.ca/ If it comes up empty, here are some things you can check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-domain-unavailable.html

Comment: 80 to 443 listener rule should be on HTTP:80 listener right? but screen shot showing on 443 listener rules. Also rather than giving the entire host name try giving `#{host}` , i.e redirect to `https://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}`

Comment: "added CNAME record www pointing to ALB" - what about `exampledomain.ai` record to alb?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala This is not about redirecting 80 to 443. Its about redirecting `https://exampledomain.ai` to `https://www.exampledomain.ai` from what I understand.

Comment: @Marcin you are right.. just woke up from sleep, heading itself says https to https :) , adding both domain `exampledomain.ai` and `https://www.exampledomain.ai` to same ALB ? and doesn't rule apply each time?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Could be. So once you solve `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` you may find yourself in a loop anyway.

Comment: @Marcin - I have added more details, can you please check

Comment: @legoscia - I am not using Route53, is it necessary to use either Route53 or add an A record set at DNS provider side?

Comment: @sachin-vairagi Have you sorted this? I have same problem. Looking at the answers none of them actually answered the question. I have same situation:

 1. Load balancer redirect from 80 to 443 works for non-www and www
 2. Route53 has an alias from example.com to www.example.com and www.example.com points to ASG
 3. Route53 can NOT point to ASG because nginx does not know of SSL certificate path beacuse it is managed by AWS Certificate Manager that is then attached to ELB

So how do we redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: @slejnej - Yes, I have resolved this issue. Please share more details about your error.

Comment: @sachin-vairagi tested all possible Route53 combinations (alias to another record -> www, alias to ASG) and with custom Listener on 443 to redirect to `https://www.#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}` and always response is `Connection timed out`. Curl does not reach the box nginx in any combination.

Comment: @slejnej - You also need to forward "non-www" traffic to "www" via your DNS provider.

Comment: @sachin-vairagi this is done via Route53, but no response on either. A record alias to www nor A record alias to ELB

Answer (score -1):

1. Create redirection rule on port 80 [image]

2. Go to route 53 and create a new cname with example.com and point to the same ALB.

Now it will work.

Comment: this is not related to the question. Adding a rule for port 80 will not resolve the problem in question where redirect needs to happen from 443 to 443.